# Delete certificate from Computer Store

Tags: powershell, certificate

I am having difficulty getting powershell to delete a certificate that was accidentally installed to all our Windows 7 machines to the Computer Store.

As an example I have included a screen shot of where the certificate is installed (this is not the actual certificate).  We have a few hundred machines so we would like to do this as automatic as possible.

If someone could provide a way to delete the certificate by Serial Number or Thumbprint that would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use the `Cert:`-PSDrive with `Get-ChildItem` and `Remove-Item`. Ex:

```
#Delete by thumbprint
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\D20159B7772E33A6A33E436C938C6FE764367396 | Remove-Item

#Delete by subject/serialnumber/issuer/whatever
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My |
Where-Object { $_.Subject -match 'Frode F' } |
Remove-Item
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me.  I also had to have a higher version PowerShell 2 installed.  Once we installed PowerShell 5 the commands worked.

Comment: Glad to help. It should be PowerShell 2-compatible too.

Comment: When using powershell 2.0 the error we got was Provider is unable to execute this operation.

When using PowerShell 5 the command worked.  For any others, the powershell version had to be installed on the workstation as well.  (This was for Thumbprint)

Comment: Which one? Thumbprint or using `where-object` filtering?

Comment: You'll need to use an argument `Remove-Item -DeleteKey` as well to remove the private key of the certificate.

Comment: DeleteKey requires using CredSSP [about Certificate Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/about/about_certificate_provider?view=powershell-5.1#deleting-certificates-and-private-keys).